# ERROR with sharp dependency when deploying nodejs app to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, sharp

i am a beginner in AWS, and I encountered this problem very early on.
I created an EB environment and a code-pipeline in AWS. So whenever I push something to the repository, the app gets deployed. So for now I just have a "Hello world" node.js app, but I want to install the sharp npm dependency for later on. When I put the dependency in the package.json file and push it to the repo, a get the following error:
[error on deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZINmI.png).
I have done a lot of googling, and I think it has something to do with setting permissions to install the sharp dependency. However, none of the solutions I found have worked so far.
If anything is unclear, I apologize and let me know :).

Comment: It's quite difficult to follow you on that one. You didn't provide enough details about the pipeline nor the process you did to set-up the Elastic Beanstalk environment. The more details you provide to reproduce the issue, the more likely it is to have an answer from someone.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @iakko, the solution underneath solved it for me, but I will update the post for any future people with the same problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reference my "workaround" solution provided in the following GitHub Issue ([Fails to install on AWS ElasticBeanstalk with node16 #3221](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3221#issuecomment-1126528844)) for a full explanation.

**Solution:**

1. Create the following Platform Hooks paths in the root directory of your application bundle.

- .platform/hooks/prebuild
- .platform/confighooks/prebuild

2. Create the following bash script (00_npm_install.sh) with execute permissions (chmod +x).

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/app/staging
sudo -u webapp npm install sharp
```

3. Validate the Application Bundle Structure.

Ex. Sample project structure:

```
~/my-app/
├── app.js
├── index.html
├── .npmrc_bkp
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── .platform
│   ├── confighooks
│   │   └── prebuild
│   │       └── 00_npm_install.sh
│   └── hooks
│       └── prebuild
│           └── 00_npm_install.sh
└── Procfile
```

4. Deploy the Application!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was working on this for way too long and this seems to be working!